# Email notifications for google calendar events

Tags: htc-desire, calendar

I am trying to create a calendar event with email notification using my HTC desire, but I can't figure how to do it. I tried both the built-in calendar app as well as mobile Google calendar website. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

For the [Google Calendar website](https://www.google.com/calendar), desktop version (the following doesn't apply to mobile version of the website, so you must request desktop version of the page from your mobile browser):

Edit or create your calendar event, under event color selection you'll see **Reminders**, by default you'll have an email sent 10 minutes before the event start time.

[image: Warning about rendering desktop site on mobile browser] [image: Google Calendar website (desktop version requested from mobile browser Chrome)]

---

The following is for the [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar) app:

Open your calendar event, go to **Reminders**, then tap the triangle selector under *Notification*, you'll see there is an ***Email*** option too.

If there is no reminder set, tap *Add reminder* first, or edit your event (the pencil icon).

[image: Calendar Event] [image: Email option in reminders]

Comment: This looks really nice. Unfortunately it seems to be incompatible with my device :(

Comment: @Grzenio I added description for Google calendar website to my answer.

Comment: Cheers. It is a real shame they didn't add this to the mobile version. Appointments without notification are equivalent to no appointment.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a new Schedule to my Google Calendar, it offered me a feature to notify me by email when the event occurs, and i have got the email also.

look a bit below there is a option offering these feature.

Comment: On the google calendar mobile web page you mean?

Comment: Correct on the bottom there is a option "reminder" that can be set to alert you by email.

Comment: I just checked the mobile calendar page, and the last item I see is `Add a person to this meeting`. Otherwise, there is only What, When, Where, Description and Created By. I can't see any `reminder` :(